# Import functions in Python

Tags: python, module, python-import

How can i import functions that make use of a variable defined in the current file?

**main.py**

```
from functions import a

x = 1

print(a())
```

**functions.py**

```
def a():
    return x
```

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Test\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.11987\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\Test\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.11987\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 410, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Test\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.11987\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 291, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Test\Google Drive\Dev\Test\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(a())
  File "c:\Users\Test\Google Drive\Dev\Test\functions.py", line 2, in a
    return x
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: The exception you mention doesn't match the issue you're describing elsewhere. Are you sure the problem is with importing `c`, rather than looking up `x`, `y` or `z` after you complete the imports and start calling the functions? If you really are getting an `ImportError`, then something else is going wrong, unrelated to your global variable design issue.

Comment: better create functions which get it as argument `a(x)`, `b(y)`, `c(z)`

Comment: i changed the question by reducing complexity (only one function) and giving the full trace back

Comment: dont want to give the variables as arguments. in reality i have more than just three.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another answer has noted, this will not work because of how Python scopes variables.

Instead, therefore, what I suggest is that you move all these variables into a *separate* file, e.g. `constants.py`:

`main.py`

```
from functions import a

print(a())
```

`constants.py`

```
X = 1
```

`functions.py`

```
from constants import X

def a():
    return X
```

Then, running `import main` prints `1`.

Answer (score 0):

There are no process-wide globals, only module-level globals. `a` uses `functions.x`, not the `x` in whatever global scope it is *called* from.

```
import functions
from functions import a, b, c

functions.x = 1
functions.y = 2
functions.z = 3

print(a())
print(b())
print(c())
```

Because Python is lexically scoped, each function keeps a reference to the global scope in which it was *defined*. Name lookups use that scope to resolve free variables.

Comment: there might be other imports that also use these variables. I think its not useful to write into the context of each import

Comment: I'm not stating a best practice: I'm describing how Python works. If you don't like it, don't use global variables.